# Update the suggested edits number when I approve or reject an edit

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, suggested-edits, review

This little box*

[image]

occasionally tells me to review the suggested edits, in this case telling me that there are 5 of them that need review.

When I go to the review page, and review them, the number doesn't change, it just stays at 5 until I go to another page or refresh the current page.

It'd be nice if it was updated as I did the review, so I can see how many are left as I am going, so that I can have the satisfaction of watching the box number decrease while I am reviewing, topped with the warm fuzzy feeling of finally making it disappear.

---

*<sub>(I apologize in advance for saving the screenshot as a JPG)</sub>

Comment: I believe this used to happen with the previous suggested edits queue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The real-time suggested edit count in the top nav was disabled a few weeks ago due to performance/inaccuracy issues. We may re-enable it in the future.

In the meantime, we've made the suggested edit count live again *while you're actively working through the Suggested Edits review queue*. That is, you should see an updated and accurate suggested edit count after approving or rejecting a suggested edit.

Comment: That's actually all I was asking for, really, was for it to update while I'm reviewing.