# The "Suggested Edits" flag does not auto-update

Tags: feature-request, review, suggested-edits, user-interface

The "Suggested Edits" flag up in the top right corner does not auto-update when the page's content changes.

Say you review the suggested edits; although the current page may say that no suggested edits remain, the flag in the top right corner still remains.

[image: StackOverflow suggested edits not updating]

The flag goes away if you **manually** refresh the entire page, but does not get updated if only the page content gets updated via JavaScript.

---

The following Meta question from 2012 addresses this question:

- [StackExchange: Update the suggested edits number when I approve or reject an edit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/150113/update-the-suggested-edits-number-when-i-approve-or-reject-an-edit)

And according to the selected answer, the flag **should** update as you approve or reject edits:

> [...] we've made the suggested edit count live again while you're actively working through the Suggested Edits review queue. That is, you should see an updated and accurate suggested edit count after approving or rejecting a suggested edit.

However, the flag does not update, so either this feature was reverted, or there is a bug preventing the suggested edit count from updating.

Comment: This number is not for suggested edits only, it's all review items.

Comment: Oops, disregard previous comment - it's only [for 10k users](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/230726/152859).